# please,give me some idea to develop multi-link arm control under ros platform

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How to start this project in step by step?
please reply..
thank you in advance...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/70303/please,give-me-some-idea-to-develop-multi-link-arm-control-under-ros-platform./) by [pavanpatel](https://answers.ros.org/users/5686/pavanpatel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2013-07-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How about looking at [MoveIt](http://moveit.ros.org/wiki/MoveIt!) or, if you're in fuerte, the [arm_navigation](http://www.ros.org/wiki/arm_navigation?distro=groovy) package?

---

Originally posted by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) with karma: 3562 on 2013-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0